# .css file not added into distribution in js only library build with rollup

Tags: javascript, css, rollup, rollup-plugin-postcss

I'm writing JS library using [rollup-starter-lib](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-starter-lib) as base of my JS library

`"version": "1.29.0"`

It has `main.js` file & `main.css` file, There is no `html` file.
`main.js` file is all about DOM manipulation, `main.css` file is necessary in implementation steps, to easily integrate this JS library, rather giving an instruction to user.

*I feel like it's .css file not creating due to tree shaking because of css not used in this JS library itself.*

Current Distribution

```
-dist
--my-faceapi-js-lib.cjs.js
--my-faceapi-js-lib.esm.js
--my-faceapi-js-lib.umd.js
```

Expected Distribution

```
-dist
--my-faceapi-js-lib.cjs.js
--my-faceapi-js-lib.esm.js
--my-faceapi-js-lib.umd.js
--my-faceapi-js-lib.css
```

copy `main.css` file into `dist` folder not expecting since it's not minifying.

rollup.config.js

```
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import pkg from './package.json';
//import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy'
//import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss'

export default [
    {
        input: 'src/main.js',
        output: {
            name: 'howLongUntilLunch',
            file: pkg.browser,
            format: 'umd'
        },
        plugins: [
            resolve(), // so Rollup can find `ms`
            commonjs() // so Rollup can convert `ms` to an ES module
        ]
    },{
        input: 'src/main.js',
        output: [
            { file: pkg.main, format: 'cjs' },
            { file: pkg.module, format: 'es' }
        ]
    }
];
```

main.js

```
import * as faceapi from "face-api.js";
...
...
...
import 'main.css';
...
...
```

Basically there is not usage of `main.css` within JS library it self. but it's necessary when integrate this library.

Answer (score 0):

You need for that to use the [rollup-plugin-postcss](https://github.com/egoist/rollup-plugin-postcss) plugin (you already have it but it's commented):

```js
// rollup.config.js
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss'
import path from 'path'

export default {
  plugins: [
    postcss({
      extract: path.resolve('dist/my-faceapi-js-lib.css'),
      plugins: []
    })
  ]
}
```

Comment: I already tried that out, didn't work, .umd.js file has `define(['exports', 'main.css']` part but it didn't create any `.css` file in `dist` folder. my guess is since there is not html use this css it's drop during the tree shaking

Comment: I had the same issue and I fixed it by adding an extra export, specifically with `input: 'path_to_css/index.css'`.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been fixed after update rollup version from `1.29.0 to` 2.26.3`
(also update relevant packages to rollup lib - not sure about related to fix)

```
"@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^15.0.0",
"@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^9.0.0",
"rollup": "^2.26.3",
```

and after adding  `['./main.css'],` as an external.

```
    {
        input: 'src/main.js',
        external: ['./main.css'],
        output: [
            { file: pkg.main, format: 'cjs' },
            { file: pkg.module, format: 'es' }
        ]
    }
```

rollup.config.js

```
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import pkg from './package.json';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss'
import path from 'path'

export default [
    {
        input: 'src/main.js',
        output: {
            name: 'my-faceapi-js-lib',
            file: pkg.browser,
            format: 'umd'
        },
        plugins: [
            postcss({
                minimize: true,
                extensions: ['.css'],
                extract: path.resolve('dist/face-auth-rnd.css'),
            }),
            resolve(), // so Rollup can find `ms`
            commonjs() // so Rollup can convert `ms` to an ES module
        ]
    },
    {
        input: 'src/main.js',
        external: ['./main.css'],
        output: [
            { file: pkg.main, format: 'cjs' },
            { file: pkg.module, format: 'es' }
        ]
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by adding an extra export which uses the CSS file as input.

```
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import pkg from './package.json';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss'

export default [
    {
        input: 'src/main.js',
        output: {
            name: 'howLongUntilLunch',
            file: pkg.browser,
            format: 'umd'
        },
        plugins: [
            resolve(), 
            commonjs() 
        ]
    },{
        input: 'src/main.css',
        output: [
            { file: "dist/main.css" }
        ],
        plugins: [
            postcss({
                minimize: true,
            }),
        ],
    }
];
```